# Object Oriented Polymorphism Logic in Java

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

We can use the same named `getWeight()` method for cat and dog objects at both implementations. I couldn't find any differences between two implementations. Is there any advantage of using polymorphism or overriding here?

First Implementation

```
public class Cat{ 
    public int getWeight() { return 5; }
}

public class Dog {
    public int getWeight() { return 7; }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Dog dog = new Dog();
        Cat cat = new Cat();

        System.out.println(dog.getWeight());
        System.out.println(cat.getWeight());
    }
}
```

Second implementation

```
public class Cat extends Animal{
    public int getWeight() { return 5; }
}

public class Dog extends Animal{
    public int getWeight() { return 7; }
}

public class Animal {   
    public int getWeight() return 10;
}

public class Main {
  
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Animal dog = new Dog();
        Animal cat = new Cat();

        System.out.println(dog.getWeight());
        System.out.println(cat.getWeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: I would just have a setWeight()  class and instance variable in Animal and not have it in the subclasses.

Comment: Voted to close "needs more focus."  There might be advantages to doing it one way or the other, but we couldn't say from your brief discussion.  In general, there is no preference.

Comment: It depends what needs to be done with `Cat` and `Dog` instances.  For example, try creating a list that contains both `Cat`s and `Dog`s using each implementation.

Comment: Flagged the question: the OP needs to explain what the usage of the code will be. More context of what's being built is needed to give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

if Cat/Dog is a subtype of Animal, then objects of type Cat/Dog may be replaced with objects of type Animal (i.e., an object of type T may be substituted with any object of a subtype S) without altering any of the desirable properties of the program (correctness, task performed, etc.)

This helps in adhering to LSP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Code that adheres to LSP is loosely dependent to each other and encourages code reusability. Code that does not adhere to the LSP is tightly coupled and creates unnecessary entanglements. In the given case if the client does not want to indulge in every animal type, they can simply use Animal variable type. Thus, making them decoupled of actual implementation subtypes, thereby being able to support any implementation of animal using same code.

However there are situations in which adhering to LSP can cause problems too. Eg: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/squarerectangle.aspx

Another advantage of overriding is that new implementations would be easy and more standardized. The new animal type implementer would know what behaviours to take care of in their implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It would be difficult to say one way or the other without knowing more about your program. Will this method be the only common attribute between these classes? Will there ever be a need to handle Animals in a generic manner? How likely is it that you will add more Animal subclasses in the future?

Comment: Please share comments in the comments section

Comment: I don't have the reputation to comment yet. Sorry, I'm a bit new to StackOverflow.

Comment: I wanted to ask that we can add new animal subtypes in the future according to requirements. Which way would be better to use? I want system to be flexible and agile.